# Json Array para Array de string C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Preciso somente pegar os nomes da moderators e viewers desse json:

```
{
  "_links": {},
  "chatter_count": 16,
  "chatters": {
    "moderators": ["gumagames", "juliavidoto", "nightbot", "pinkpanthersz_", "victoriia66"],
    "staff": [],
    "admins": [],
    "global_mods": [],
    "viewers": ["andreschramm", "anotheruselessbot", "barbosza", "brancoxp", "froydz1515", "hurato2", "luiz522", "phoenixlabella", "rockmam", "sumarilion1988", "xoverxkill"]
  }
}
```

Estou usando JSON.Net mas não consegui um resultado satisfatório.

Comment: O que você já tentou?

Comment: Olhe se é [**isso**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WzSBx3) o que você precisa.

Comment: @Brunno Estava fazendo assim mesmo Brunno, estava declarando as classes de maneira errônea, mesmo assim agradeço pela solução!

Comment: @MarcosBarbosa legal, postei como resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa criar uma classe de acordo com o seu Json, e após isso basta usar:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SeuObjeto>(stringJson);
```

Que ele fara o parse do Json para sua classe e retornara o objeto instanciado.

Segue o [**fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WzSBx3).

Gerando as classes do Json em C#: [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Usando o comando de linha `jq`:

```
jq ".chatters.moderators,.chatters.viewers" ex.json
```

produz:

```
[
  "gumagames",
  "juliavidoto",
  "nightbot",
  "pinkpanthersz_",
  "victoriia66"
]
[
  "andreschramm",
  "anotheruselessbot",
  "barbosza",
  "brancoxp",
  "froydz1515",
  "hurato2",
  "luiz522",
  "phoenixlabella",
  "rockmam",
  "sumarilion1988",
  "xoverxkill"
]
```

ou 
`jq ".chatters.moderators+.chatters.viewers"` para obter um único array